# How to export far manager files highlighting scheme

Tags: far-manager

How to export and import far manager  files colorings?

`far.exe /export`

does not export these settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Copy the file `%AppData%\Far Manager\Profile\highlight.db` to the new machine.

---

See [FarManager 3: export settings AND history](https://superuser.com/questions/1160619/farmanager-3-export-settings-and-history/1267678#1267678) on what these `.db` files contain.

---

**Example:**

I've created a file highlighting named `abc` for the files matching `*.qwertyuiozzz`.

```
   ╔══════════════════════════ Files highlighting ══════════════════════════╗
   ║ Name: abc                                                             ↓║
   ╟────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╢
   ║ [x] Mask: *.qwertyuiopzzz                                             ↓║
   ╟──────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────╢
```

The SQLite DB contains this:

```
SQLite: table_values
key_id │ name                        │ value
───────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────
2      │ Title                       │ abc
2      │ UseMask                     │ 1
2      │ Mask                        │ *.qwertyuiopzzz
2      │ UseDate                     │ 0
2      │ DateType                    │ 0
2      │ DateTimeAfter               │ 0
2      │ DateTimeBefore              │ 0
...
```